# New Xcode 6 Project - How to run in the iOS 7 Simulator

Tags: ios7, ios-simulator, xcode6

I try to create a new project with Xcode 6 that also runs on iOS 7. I've created a new project and then did the following:

1. Set Project's iOS Deployment Target to 7.0
2. Referenced a Launch Image Source in the Assets

Still, when trying to run on an iOS 7 simulator, the following error is shown:

"iPhone 5s not available. Please select a different device and try again."

(My older projects run fine on iOS 7 simulators.)

**How I can make a new project run in the iOS 7 simulator?**

*EDIT*

The output of `xcrun simctl list` is the following:

```
== Device Types ==
iPhone 4s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-4s)
iPhone 5 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5)
iPhone 5s (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-5s)
iPhone 6 Plus (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6-Plus)
iPhone 6 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPhone-6)
iPad 2 (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-2)
iPad Retina (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Retina)
iPad Air (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.iPad-Air)
Resizable iPhone (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPhone)
Resizable iPad (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDeviceType.Resizable-iPad)
== Runtimes ==
iOS 7.0 (7.0 - Unknown) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-0) (unavailable, runtime path not found)
iOS 7.1 (7.1 - Unknown) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-7-1) (unavailable, runtime path not found)
iOS 8.0 (8.0 - 12A365) (com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-8-0)
== Devices ==
-- iOS 7.0 --
    iPhone 4s (9A55186B-9B91-4526-A2AB-EF0C49F592A4) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPhone 5 (D326EE14-21DA-4FA5-A229-F0BACDA6C9F3) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPhone 5s (1AC03181-38D5-4C24-9928-4EFDE83D0ACD) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPad 2 (212A00A7-1D1F-4392-8AE6-24C46EA9A507) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPad Retina (9471D6C8-DDE7-4D08-B015-89CA02ED4C46) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPad Air (E84ADD9C-7BA4-4EBF-B98E-DB6EAF99EFA6) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
-- iOS 7.1 --
    iPhone 4s (836A9B30-D104-4D54-98A2-479F7F35F4EC) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPhone 5 (39EB7E74-4665-492B-9097-F454D083CFD8) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPhone 5s (DAE6E1F3-E4F1-4D4F-9C16-73B495A08415) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPad 2 (D34D496D-39CA-4D2E-9C6A-C5EB7B62C8DC) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPad Retina (8EFF2BF2-F639-46C2-AB21-8B28858DF778) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
    iPad Air (434AB478-DD08-481D-A75D-3EA94A440814) (Shutdown) (unavailable)
-- iOS 8.0 --
    iPhone 4s (EEAA9E7C-867E-4E71-99CE-A5C729FB2F21) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 5 (DA90266D-1FF5-4E84-B806-DBE49F1A86DB) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 5s (B673A5D8-7992-41AE-9B43-200C064ECFDA) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 Plus (19F9C682-B4D8-488B-82C4-8B5BAD8D38FB) (Shutdown)
    iPhone 6 (2FCC7DD6-2274-4B7F-A151-1A49AB31AE65) (Booted)
    iPad 2 (801852DD-7EFA-4336-9686-42C5D65DAABD) (Shutdown)
    iPad Retina (314D3C76-6D20-466B-AD61-567CE202556F) (Shutdown)
    iPad Air (5B47FA82-F1F6-43C2-A373-BABBEFA0AB22) (Shutdown)
    Resizable iPhone (8F4B8FAF-AEB9-4782-AC09-6F8B4BDD37AA) (Shutdown)
    Resizable iPad (DEBDB255-8650-4B8D-B161-D9FA26331ACD) (Shutdown)
```

Comment: What is the output of 'xcrun simctl list'?

Comment: I updated the answer - but I have another hunch: recently I updated to Xcode 6.0.1, maybe I need to redownload the simulators?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the Devices window, delete all devices one by one. Now add them back one by one. Now restart the computer (not just Xcode). This will leave you with only good devices and you'll know whether you need to download the older simulators.

Comment: The part with adding back the devices did not work - because there only was iOS 8 available. Seems like the update to Xcode 6.0.1 really broke the 7.x simulators. Redownloading simulators now.

Comment: That was exactly why I suggested it. If the simulators were gone, you would not be able to add back those devices. And that is just what happened.

Comment: I sort of think this is terrible advice.  I did this and now have to manually add them back. I get your point of now you know, but I think the answer below of downloading the 7.1 simulation probably would have worked.  Extra Work = Bummed.

Comment: @badweasel actually I think cleaning out all your simulators from time to time is a good idea. And let's not exaggerate how much work is involved....

Comment: It's a task that would have taken an hour or more. So I think people should know that.  I ended up only adding a couple cause I didn't have the time to restore it.  Someday I'll wipe out Xcode and reload it.  That would take less time than adding them manually one by one. There should be a single click way to add all the simulator combinations instead of having to do them on at a time.

Comment: The answer by Veight Zhou below should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 64):

I meet this problem too.

1. `Preferences` -> `Downloads` -> `Components`
2. Then click the download button.

   - If you've downloaded them before, Xcode will install them directly.

Maybe you've just update your Xcode.
Xcode 6 is not installed 7.x simulators as default. However, you installed them on previous version Xcode.

Comment: Upvotes drew me to this answer, thankfully. I'm glad I did this rather than "deleting one by one" and then having to restart the computer, which I was about to do.

Comment: Same problem ... it seems that all that is necessary is to download the missing simulators within xcode; no deleting, no rebooting, no mess, no fuss. Too bad xcode can't figure this out on its own and provide a meaning message.

Answer (score 4):

I resolve this issue by performing the following steps:

1) From my Xcode 6.1 --> Opens  available simulators/devices Devices List.

2) Then Click on the bottom of the list more simulator button --> Download simulator windows opens.

3) Download your desire simulator 7.0 or 7.1 or both.

If simulators downloaded before,then Xcode will install them automatically.

Check the Screen Shots:

[image]  [image]

Hope this will help you out cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the output of simctl list, you should see the 8.0 simulators in Xcode but not the 7.x simulators.  The 7.x simulators will appear once you download and install the 7.x simulator runtimes.

Comment: Yes I did see them, but they were broken. Updating from Xcode 6.0.0 GM to 6.0.1 broke them.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "broken"?  What makes you think they are broken?  They seem to be behaving correctly in that they are not listed as available because you need to download the 7.x runtime in order to boot them.

Comment: They were listed. I could not run a project on them, the error in my question was displayed.

Comment: Odd.  I am not sure where that error would come from.  If you see it again, please provide a screenshot and also look in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator.log for possible additional info.

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem. And I have fixed it. When you update to Xcode 6.0+, the Xcode will break the runtime of iOS 7 simulators. Though you have the Devices of iOS 7.1 but without runtime, the simulators are not available. You must download the 7.1 runtime again.

But we all know download the simulators in Xcode is very painful. An easier way is to copy the "iOS 7.1 SDKs" form other's Mac (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs).