# How to install iOS 7.0 simulator in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, ios7, xcode6

I would like to test my app with iOS 7.0 simulator in Xcode 6.1 6A1052d under Yosemite. How to do it?

Comment: Xcode (top left corner) > Preferences > Downloads > Simulators.

Comment: I can see the iOS 7.1 simulator only.

Comment: See also [New Xcode 6 project: how to run in the iOS 7 simulator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26043854)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the xCode>Preferences.
And then go here:
[image]

Comment: I can see iOS 7.1 only.

Comment: I assume that you have th Yosemite Mac OS X.
It doesn't support 7.0 anymore. Here the same answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364239/ios-7-0-simulator-not-showing-under-downloads-in-xcode-6-0-1-running-osx-yosemi

Comment: Yes, I am under Yosemite

Comment: I'm on Mavericks and there is no 7.0 :(