# Unable to boot the Simulator.(Xcode Version 7.2 (7C68))

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

my Xcode has build succeeded,but Simulator shows the error 'Unable to boot the Simulator',I have tried many solutions, still can not work, I reinstall the Xcode, restart my mac,reset the Simulator content and settings,add the new Simulator to retry,still not work!!!!!!Help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043854/new-xcode-6-project-how-to-run-in-the-ios-7-simulator/26053671#26053671

Answer (score -1, accepted):

go into utilities > terminal and type the following commands:

```
csrutil disable
reboot
```

and everything will work.

Comment: This answer needs an explanation , and a warning. "The rootless feature is aimed at preventing Mac OS X compromise by malicious code, whether intentionally or accidentally, and essentially what SIP does is lock down specific system level locations in the file system while simultaneously preventing certain processes from attaching to system-level processes."  "the vast majority of Mac users should not disable rootless. Disabling rootless is aimed exclusively at advanced Mac users. Do so at your own risk, this is not specifically recommended."

Comment: FYI, Also, typing that into a terminal on OS X 10.11.6 does not execute the command; instead says "csrutil: failed to modify system integrity configuration. This tool needs to be executed from the Recovery OS."  (Meaning it is necessary to reboot Mac into Recovery Mode, before doing this.)

Comment: My colleague had the same problem and tried all other things with no luck. What he finally did to fix it is that he disabled `csrutil`, restarted, then opened the simulator. After the simulator has run properly, he re-enabled `csrutil` and restarted. The simulator then worked normally with `csrutil` enabled and no vulnerability.